# How can I change the Window Title text and background colors on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, aero, display-settings

I have tried certain registry edits to resolve this in the past without success. I'd like a black active-window title bar, but when it's changed the typical aero way the font has such little contrast against the background it becomes difficult to read. I know there has to be a regedit for this, could someone point me in the right direction?